# Jinja: Retrieve an IP address from a list of dictionaries - filters

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am getting really close but having trouble figuring out the correct jinja filter to use to easily grab this IP address:

Here is the JSON data that I get from an API call to route53 on Amazon Web Services AWS

```
{    "record_sets": {
        "IsTruncated": true,
        "ResourceRecordSets": [
            {
                "Name": "student1.junostesting.rhdemo.io.",
                "ResourceRecords": [
                    {
                        "Value": "35.183.128.49"
                    }
                ],
                "TTL": 3600,
                "Type": "A"
            }
        ],
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false
    }
}
```

The filter I am currently using is this:

```
{{ record_sets.ResourceRecordSets | selectattr("Name", "match", "student1.junostesting.rhdemo.io") | map(attribute="ResourceRecords") | join(',') }}
```

This returns the following list of dictionaries....

```
[{u'Value': u'35.183.128.49'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: (This example uses [json_query](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) filter )

```
---
- name: JSON query extraction
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: Set facts for search
      set_fact:
        name_to_find: 'student1.junostesting.rhdemo.io.'
        route53_json_string: '{"record_sets":{"IsTruncated":true,"ResourceRecordSets":[{"Name":"student1.junostesting.rhdemo.io.","ResourceRecords":[{"Value":"35.183.128.49"}],"TTL":3600,"Type":"A"}],"changed":false,"failed":false}}'

    - name: Convert json string to facts
      set_fact:
        route53_data: "{{ route53_json_string | from_json }}"

    - name: get IP
      set_fact:
        ip: "{{ route53_data | json_query(\"record_sets.ResourceRecordSets[?Name=='\" + name_to_find + \"'].ResourceRecords[0].Value\") }}"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out I could do this with->

`{{ (record_sets.ResourceRecordSets | selectattr("Name", "match", "student1.junostesting.rhdemo.io") | map(attribute="ResourceRecords") | flatten | first) | first }}`

or this->

`{{ (record_sets.ResourceRecordSets | selectattr("Name", "match", "student1.junostesting.rhdemo.io") | map(attribute="ResourceRecords") | first | first)['Value'] }}`